# Create new path in Firebase Realtime Database programmatically?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase documentation I don't found the anweser. How to add a new path in real-time database programmatically in Javascript? Like (just an example):

standard path: https://testapp.firebaseio.com/

And in the app I want to say something like: If this, then create a path like this:
https://testapp.firebaseio.com/info/important/personal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys and paths in the Firebase Database are automatically created when you write a value to them. So to generate the path `info/important/personal`, you would write a value under it. For example:

```
firebase.database().ref('info/important/personal').set(true);
```

This will generate the following JSON:

```
{
  "info": {
    "important": {
      "personal": true
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the inverse is also true: Firebase will automatically remove empty keys/paths. So if you delete the `true` above, the entire JSON will be deleted.

Comment: ohhhhh i dont knew that. that helped me a lot. thanks