# How to make just the key in firebase realtime database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make the key, just key not value, firebase realtime database in android. For example, I want to make just "title", not want to set the value "first time of using ...". How to make just the key??

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911165/create-an-empty-child-record-in-firebase, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480575

Answer (score 0):

This Firebase Realtime Database works like a JSON. So it has to be formatted as Key-Value.

If you don't want value, just try to put `blank` like `""` into title's value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, um... I mean that I don't want to put any value in "title". Because I want to make key and value in "title". When I put value in "title", I can't make key and value in "title". Just want to make key.

Comment: `Because I want to make key and value in "title". When I put value in "title", I can't make key and value in "title"`
Really not sure about your question. But i'm pretty sure that it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an empty child in Realtime Database.  As soon as a child no longer has a value or other children, it simply stops being visible in the dashboard.  And when you query it, the snapshot will be empty, as if it never created in the first place.